# How can I make a DEBUG function in C++ such as ConditionalAttribute in C#

Tags: c++, debugging

In C#, one can make a method such as this:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
private void MyFunction()
{
}
```

In release, this method will no longer "exist".

Using C++, I have a class where I want to perform the same assertions at the beginning of every method, so I would like to put the group of assertions in their own method. If I chose to do it that way, would I have to rely on the compiler optimizing out an empty function (since asserts will be optimized out as well)? For example:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
   void DebugFunction()
   {
       assert(...);
       assert(...);
       assert(...);
       // ...
   }
};
```

Or would I have to introduce a macro:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define DebugFunction
#endif
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I believe you want `#ifndef NDEBUG` there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler will definitely optimize out the empty functions.  I would prefer the function of `asserts` over different versions of the code for debug and release.  Of course, you should name the function appropriately, and document your reasons as well :-)

If, for some reason, you absolutely did have the urge to use `#ifndef`, make sure you do it *inside* the `CheckState()` function.  This allows you to perform checks in release mode as well, should you later decide to do so.  For example:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    void CheckState()
    {
        assert(...); 
        assert(...);

#ifndef NDEBUG
        // some expensive check to only run on Debug builds
#endif

        // Some check you want to always make
   }
}
```